# Use GetAllIncluding to get multiple levels in a single call

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

Using ABP Repository pattern we are trying to create a single query to retrieve a set of entities, along with their children, and the childrens children

Entity X -> one to many Entity Y -> one to many Entity Z

(think Invoice > InvoiceItem > InvoiceItemParts for example)

The Abp repository pattern provides for retrieving at least 1 set of children using

result = _repositoryInvoice.GetAllIncluding(x => x.InvoiceItem)

is there a way using LINQ to include InvoiceItemParts in this 1 query?  If not, what is the recommended way to retrieve all child nav properties and all levels using a single call.

The main goal is making it so we don't have to make multiple round trips to the DB when accessing the child properties along with the child properties of those children.

thanks
jasen

Comment: I don't know about ABP Repository, but it sounds like you ask about `dbSetX.Include(x => x.ItemsY.Select(y => y.ItemsZ))` for EF6 or `dbSetX.Include(x => x.ItemsY).ThenInclude(y => y.ItemsZ)` for EF core. Did I misinterpret your problem?

Comment: There is no such method (that includes a variable number of navigation properties). The generated SQL has to be determined solely by the schema in order for EF to be generated, what you want (I think) is some way to include one more entity type if you got some entities referencing it, but then EF would have to retrieve data while generating the query, which it will not do.

Comment: I wasn't looking for a variable number of properties, just basically trying to figure out what the equivalent to "ThenInclude" might be in AspNetBoilerPlate.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Decided to just create my own custom repository and use EFCore .Include and .ThenInclude directly.   Turns out AspNetBoilerPlate has no support for querying navigation properties beyond their immediate children of the root entity being queried.

Microsoft provides some great examples of using .Include and .ThenInclude:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

`GetAllIncluding` accepts params, so you can specify multiple attributes:

```
var result = await _repositoryInvoice
            .GetAllIncluding(x => x.InvoiceItem,
                             x => x.InvoiceItemParts)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I think this method will work if you only need to load the children entities, not for the grandchildren entity.

Answer (score 0):

With `IRepository<>` there are the method `Include` and `ThenInclude`, where you can use the same structure of EF Core standard.

```
_repository.GetAll().Include(d => d.Child).ThenInclude(c => c.GrandChild).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
```